# Can I use genymotion without the graphics card supporting open gl 2.0

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, genymotion, android-support-design

[I get this error, I have updated the drivers but it won't work. There is no good alternative of Genymotion. Is there any way to bypass this problem?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PJPYD.png)

Edit: Any solution without upgrading the graphics card.

Comment: just install or update you graphics card driver

Comment: I can not buy new one thats why I asked for alternative solution.

Comment: just install driver not a hardware

Comment: I did, It did not work.

Comment: then does not work,

Comment: can you try running genymotion with ubuntu?

Comment: That card was too old to support 'open gl 2.0'. After few weeks of that problem, I bough new one and problem was solved.